# too many bytes written - HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, networking

i have written an application which would test the performance of a servlet.
the code that i have written works well with some requests.
if i increase to more connections then some times i get "too many bytes written " exception.

```
int startRange = 0, endRange = 10000;
HttpsURLConnection c = null;

c = getHttpsConnection(URL);
c.setDoInput(true);
c.setDoOutput(true);
c.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",(cotentLength+1));
c.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(contentLength+1);
c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","appplication/zip");
c.setRequestMethod("POST");
c.setRequestProperty("Content-Range", "bytes "+startRange+"-"+endRange+"/"+filesize);

OutputStream op = c.getOutputStream();
```

i compute the fixed chunk to send into `byte[] partBuf = new byte[contentLength+1];`

then

```
op.write(partBuf)
String range = c.getHeaderField("Range");

in.close();
op.flush();
op.close();
```

i dont get "too many bytes written error" upto certain requests sent, 
too many requests sent gives me this error only sometimes .. 
how do i handle this scenario?

usually for testing, i spawn some requests varying from 10, 100, 500, 1000 .. which inturn hits a servlet that receives the data in chunks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of typo's in your sample code, so it is unclear what your real code does.  However this looks very wrong:

```
   c.setRequestProperty("Content-Range", startRange-endRange/filesize);
```

The content of that header should be a String, but you seem to be sending an integer value.  Here's an example of what the header *should* look like from the HTTP 1.1 spec.

```
   HTTP/1.1 206 Partial content
   Date: Wed, 15 Nov 1995 06:25:24 GMT
   Last-Modified: Wed, 15 Nov 1995 04:58:08 GMT
   Content-Range: bytes 21010-47021/47022
   Content-Length: 26012
   Content-Type: image/gif
```

---

Your edited version is still incorrect.  It should be this:

```
c.setRequestProperty("Content-Range", 
                     "bytes " + startRange + "-" + endRange + "/" + filesize);
```

... assuming that those variables have the appropriate values.

---

Now that you have fixed those errors, my next point of suspicion is the values themselves ... and the `contentLength` value.

And if that isn't the answer, consider the possibility that the server or servlet does not support "Content-Range" for POST.

Comment: there .. i have edited and fixed my typo .. Please tell me what can be done to fix it ?

Comment: is it got to do with the way i have opened the connection, should i make the connection a member data in  class and reuse the same connection for each request for a Thread ?

Comment: Yes please ignore the typo ..  the test application  works well.. 
the complete program has it these things as i have already mentioned. Please tell me the solution to tackle it.

Comment: the content length is correct, for eg, if i use this application to run test for say some 50 or 100 threads they run just fine without any errors but as i increase the number of threads, i get this error

Answer (score 1):

`c.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(x)` requires you to write **exactly** `x` bytes to the stream. From the Javadocs:

> An exception will be thrown if the application attempts to write more
>   data than the indicated content-length, or if the application closes
>   the OutputStream before writing the indicated amount.

For example I had a similar problem when I made the following silly mistake:

```
http.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(body.length());
try (OutputStream os = http.getOutputStream()) {
    os.write(body.getBytes("UTF-8"));
} ...
```

This worked until an accented character appeared in `body`. That made the byte length differ from the String length, which led to `java.io.IOException: too many bytes written`.

To make matters more confusing, the try-with-resources caused another exception: `Suppressed: java.io.IOException: insufficient data written`. I'm still not sure where that came from but it went away when I passed the proper length to `setFixedLengthStreamingMode`.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this `java.io.IOException: too many bytes to write to stream` error, and it happened because of non-ASCII characters in the body text. The sending code incorrectly assumed the length of text to be equal to the number of characters. Since the code was a test harness, it was easier to delete these characters than to fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the wrong content-length value. There is no need to set it at all: Java does that for you. Just remove the code.

Comment: i tried this, even then i get this error. each thread tries to upload 1MB file which are sent in chunks of 30KB, so each time there is a 30KB chunk sent, a connection is opened and then its disconnected.